# How to get data inputed from dropdown menu in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm a newbee in Laravel and i start to do a dropdown login menu
but i don't know how to directly login from this form in Laravel, which don't need using auth/login. Thank you so much!

This is the dropdown sample i try

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.active-links').click(function () {
        if ($('#signin-dropdown').is(":visible")) {
            $('#signin-dropdown').hide()
   $('#session').removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $('#signin-dropdown').show()
   $('#session').addClass('active');
        }
  return false;
    });
 $('#signin-dropdown').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(document).click(function() {
        $('#signin-dropdown').hide();
  $('#session').removeClass('active');
    });
});     
</script>
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
* {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

body {
 background:#fff;
 position:relative;
 font:13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

a { 
 text-decoration:none; 
 color:#00c6ff;
}

h1 {
 font: 4em normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 padding: 20px; margin-top: 100px;
 text-align:center;
}

h1 small{
 font: 0.2em normal  Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 text-transform:uppercase; letter-spacing: 0.2em; line-height: 5em;
 display: block;
}

.content {width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; overflow: hidden;}

#top-stuff {
 left:0;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 width:100%;
 z-index:12;
}

#top-bar-out {
 display:block;
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height:40px;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #333333, #111111);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#333333), to(#111111));
 background:  -o-linear-gradient(top, #333333, #111111);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#333333', EndColorStr='#111111');
 box-shadow:0 1px 2px #666666;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #666666;
}

.active-links {
 position:absolute;
 right:8px;
 top:0;
}
#container {
    width:780px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

#topnav {
    text-align:right;
}

#session {
 cursor:pointer;
 display:inline-block;
 height:20px;
 padding:10px 12px;
 vertical-align: top;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

#session.active, #session:hover {
 background:rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
 color:fff;
}


a#signin-link {
 color:#bababa;
 position:relative;
}

a#signin-link em {
 font-size:10px;
 font-style:normal;
 margin-right:4px;
}

a#signin-link strong {
 color:#fff;
}

#signin-dropdown {
 background-color:#202020;
 border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
 border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
 box-shadow:0 1px 2px #666666;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #666666;
 min-height:200px;
 min-width:160px;
 position:absolute;
 right:0;
 display:none;
}

#signin-dropdown form{
 cursor:pointer;
 padding:10px;
 text-align:left;
}

#signin-dropdown .textbox span { color:#BABABA;}
#signin-dropdown .textbox input { width:200px; }

fieldset { 
 border:none; 
}

form.signin .textbox label { 
 display:block; 
 padding-bottom:7px; 
}

form.signin .textbox span { 
 display:block;
}

form.signin p, form.signin span { 
 color:#999; 
 font-size:11px; 
 line-height:18px;
} 

form.signin .textbox input { 
 background:#666666; 
 border-bottom:1px solid #333;
 border-left:1px solid #000;
 border-right:1px solid #333;
 border-top:1px solid #000;
 color:#fff; 
 -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
 font:13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 padding:6px 6px 4px;
}

form.signin .remb { 
 padding:9px 0; 
 position:relative; 
 text-align:right;
}

form.signin .remb .remember { 
 text-align:left; 
 position:absolute; 
 left:0;
}

.button { 
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #f3f3f3, #dddddd);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f3f3f3), to(#dddddd));
 background:  -o-linear-gradient(top, #f3f3f3, #dddddd);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#f3f3f3', EndColorStr='#dddddd');
 border-color:#000; 
 border-width:1px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 color:#333;
 cursor:pointer;
 display:inline-block;
 padding:4px 7px;
 margin:0;
 font:12px; 
}

.button:hover { background:#ddd; }

</style>
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Signin Dropdown Box with jQuery</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="top-stuff">
 <div id="top-bar-out">
     <div id="container">
     <div id="topnav">
        <div class="active-links">
            <div id="session">
            <a id="signin-link" href="#">
            <em>Have an account?</em>
            <strong>Sign in</strong>
            </a>
            </div>
             <div id="signin-dropdown">
          <form method="post" class="signin" action="#">
                <fieldset class="textbox">
             <label class="username">
                <span>Username or email</span>
                <input id="username" name="username" value="" type="text" autocomplete="on">
                </label>
                
                <label class="password">
                <span>Password</span>
                <input id="password" name="password" value="" type="password">
                </label>
                </fieldset>
                
                <fieldset class="remb">
                <label class="remember">
                <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="remember_me" />
                <span>Remember me</span>
                </label>
                <button class="submit button" type="button">Sign in</button>
                </fieldset>
                <p>
                <a class="forgot" href="#">Forgot your password</a>
                <br>
                <a class="mobile" href="#">Already using Twitter via SMS?</a>
                </p>
                </form>
           </div>
          </div>
                </div>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `dropdown login menu`?? what is that?? please elobarate a bit.

Comment: i mean it a dropdown menu type, which contain login form :)

Comment: @Shui What is the problem in your code ?

Comment: this is html, now i want add php to it by using laravel for users can log in from it

Comment: What you can do is add an event on click of submit button this event grabs the data from the login form i.e username and password and posts this data to your controller using ajax, your controller then verifies whether the supplied credentials are correct or not and recturns the json_encoded daa back to your function which sent the ajax call, now according to the response show an error message or login success and refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

Please look at you form open tag `<form method="post" class="signin" action="#">`
In you can see action is `#` change it to another url that provides authenfication of user, also you will need to add CSRF token, if you didn't disable CSRF protection. To learn how to add it please look [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-protection)